# JS Function wont initialize upon button click

Tags: javascript, html, dom

When I add brackets to the function it will initialize immediately telling me it's not poor syntax, but when I remove them it won't initiate upon the click. help would be appreciated Thanks.

```
        <nav class="nav-box">
            <div class="nav-header">
                <h1> heading here </h1>
            </div>
            <div>
                <ul class="main-nav">
                    <li><a id='about-btn' class='button nav' href="#">about</a></li>
                    <li><a id='services-btn' class='button nav' href="#" >services</a></li>
                    <li><a id='contact-btn' class='button nav' href="#">contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>              
        </nav>
```

```
let about_button = document.getElementById('about-btn');
about_button.onclick=scroll

function scroll(){
    let scroller = {
        top: 950,
        left: 0,
        behavior : "smooth"
    }
    window.scrollBy(scroller);
}
```

Comment: Function is getting initiated. May be some other issue

Comment: Make sure your body has enough height to scroll.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is initiated  , but since you are using a tag with href then onclick will redirect to the URL ! To prevent it either remove href tag or see this =>

```
about_button.onclick = function (e){
    e.preventDefault()
    scroll()
}
```

> Make sure the default a tags behaviour is prevented or else will try to redirect

Comment: @catShietBud Please mark this question as solved if your problem was solved also if any doubt about it you can comment me !

Answer (score 0):

First of all your body does not have enough contain. Your html body need to be height more than 950px. Then you need to put addEventListener with click event

```js
let about_button = document.getElementById('about-btn');

about_button.addEventListener('click',(e)=>{
    e.preventDefault();
   console.log("Trigger");
    let scroller = {
        top: 950,
        left: 0,
        behavior : "smooth"
    }
    window.scrollBy(scroller);
})
```

```html
        <nav class="nav-box">
            <div class="nav-header">
                <h1> heading here </h1>
            </div>
            <div>
                <ul class="main-nav">
                    <li><a id='about-btn' class='button nav' href="#">about</a></li>
                    <li><a id='services-btn' class='button nav' href="#" >services</a></li>
                    <li><a id='contact-btn' class='button nav' href="#">contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>              
        </nav>
        <p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p><p>
        &nbsp;
        </p>
```